# Getting x,y coordinates on click without passing the event input

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, overwrite, confirm

Well, I have a problem : How can I get the coordinates on a click without passing the event input? I can't figure out a method of doing this that works in Firefox, because I want to get the coordinates when a confirm action is being triggered using a modified `window.confirm` function. Example :

```
window.confirm = function() {
    if ( arguments[0] )
    {
        text_confirm = arguments[0];
        x_pos = window.event.clientX;
        y_pos = window.event.clientY;
    }
}
```

This is triggerd on :

```
<a onclick="if (confirm('Are you sure?')) document.location='....'; return false;" href="javascript:void(1);"></a>
```

This code works in Chrome, but obviously in Firefox I have to use something like `onClick="getCoords(event);"`. And I cannot sent the event input inside the overwrite on the window.confirm.

Another approach is also appreciated but know this :

!! I cannot change the action on the `onClick` button, it must only have the `window.confirm()` !

Comment: Can you bind a second handler and use that `event` to retrieve the x,y positions? If so you could store that somewhere and use it in your confirm function.

Comment: Yes you are right. I could do that, but it is not recommended. I will probably do this if no other solution is found.

Comment: Ty Shikyo, fortunately for me I can change the onClick event because the links are generated using `sprintf( DELETE, $url_delete )` and I can insert in the DELETE constant another function in front of the confirm action to get the Coords.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply save coords in variable and then use them in function:

```
var coords = getCoords(event); if (confirm('Are you sure?')) { // use stored coords and stuff ... }
```

If you have no access to html with this node, you can redefine listener in your code:

```
$('#element').click(function(event) {
  if (!confirm('are you sure?'))
    return false;

  getCoords(event);
  // ...

  return false;
});
```

Comment: This would not work for me because it is imposible to attach an id to the element and because I have many items I have to treat per page.